# Can't generate right graph for bellman-ford algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, bellman-ford

I have an implementation of the algorithm of Bellman - Ford.
The input program supplied a list of edges.
Without optimization it looks like this:

```
int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < number_of_vertices; i++) {
            distances[i] = MAX;
        }
        distances[source] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < number_of_vertices - 1; ++i) {

            for (j = 0; j < e; ++j) { //here i am calculating the shortest path
                if (distances[edges.get(j).source] + edges.get(j).weight < distances[edges.get(j).destination]) {
                    distances[edges.get(j).destination] = distances[edges.get(j).source] + edges.get(j).weight;
                }
            }
        }
```

it has the complexity of O(V * E)
But with optimization his works very fast. it looks like

```
while (true) {

            boolean any = false;
            for (j = 0; j < e; ++j) { //here i am calculating the shortest path
                if (distances[edges.get(j).source] + edges.get(j).weight < distances[edges.get(j).destination]) {
                    distances[edges.get(j).destination] = distances[edges.get(j).source] + edges.get(j).weight;
                    any = true;
                }
            }
            if (!any) break;
        }
```

In practice, if the number of vertices , for example ten thousand , in the outer loop had only 10-12 passes iterations instead of 10 thousand, and the algorithm completes its work .

This is my generate code:

```
//q - vertices

for (int q = 100; q <= 20000; q += 100) {
          List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
                        if (i == j) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        double random = Math.random();
                        if (random < 0.005) {
                            int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 100000);
                           edges.add(new Edge(i, j, x));
                            edges++;
                        }
                    }

                }
              //write edges to file edges
            }
```

But I need to generate a graph on which it will not be so fast to finish his work. That can be changed in the generator?

Comment: So your question is : what does a hard example look like for Bellman-Ford (or shortest path algorithms in general)?

Comment: @gilleain 
yes, with my generator the number of iterations of the outer loop is too small, and it is necessary to randomly generate "hard" / "simple" graphs for this algorithm , with which he could not finish the job so quickly .

Comment: @gilleain 
I need it, because I have the realization of Dijkstra algorithm , which uses a binary tree , and has algorithmic complexity O (E * log (V)) and working time around as well , as this implementation Bellman Ford with optimization

Comment: Understood. Then it seems more like a maths question - what class of graph has a large number of short paths? Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of Bellman Ford algorithm like you said is O(|E|*|V|). In your generator, the probability of adding an edge is negligible (0.005) which is why according to me the code works fast.

Increase the probability, there shall be more edges and consequently the Bellman Ford shall then take longer time.

Comment: In my generator, for example, if vertices = 10000 -> edges ≈500000. 
But the number of iterations of the outer loop is not affected . If I expose percentage generating edge 30 % , and for example i have 3000 vertices, i have 10 iteration on while(true) loop, without optimization had to be 3000. 
In this example Dijkstra running  3523 milliseconds , Bellman Ford 3024 , although the complexity of Dijkstra O (E * log (V))

Comment: @Birthright a graph with 10000 vertices with 500000 edges is not dense. In my opinion the difference will become apparent only on larger and denser graphs (more vertices and edges).

Comment: i testing algorithms in sparse graphs. But OK. If the generation probability is 80 %, I get that's what.
Vertices = 3000, Edges = 7196374, number of iterations on while(true) loop = 9. Bellman-Ford - 4851 millisecond, Dijkstra using binary tree - 5311 millisecond

Comment: If the number of iterations of the while loop are just 9 then Bellman ford shall take O(9*E) and Dijkstra's will take O(log(3000) * E).

Comment: So I need to increase the number of iterations in the loop , it is possible , if in a different way to generate the graph . Maybe I am wrong somewhere, and if I generate another graph , then Dijkstra also will work longer,  but but presently I don't like that Dijkstra is slower than the Bellman Ford